# Time converter "071953Z" (ZULU TO CURRENT TIME)

Tags: ios, swift, time, swift3, converters

I'm using an api that gives me the following time format:

> "071953Z"
>
> - 07 is the day
> - 19 is the hours
> - 53 are the minutes
> - Z is Zulu time

As you can see, there is no current month and year, i also want that to be added but i dont know how.

Could you help me to convert this to the current time? Thanks!

Comment: Where should month and year come from?

Comment: I want also to add this if possible.

Comment: Your problem is still unclear (to me). What should "071953Z" be? January 7, 2013? Or May 7, 1685? Or do you mean the 7th day of the *current* month/year?

Comment: the 7th day of the current month

Comment: If you know that the API is giving you the current day/time can you not just add in the current month/year into your logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to store the partial-datetime in a `DateComponents`. Then you can add a month and year to it and use `Foundation`'s calendar API to do what you want:

```
extension DateComponents {
    static func from(str: String) -> DateComponents? {
        guard str.characters.count == 7 else {
            return nil
        }

        var components = DateComponents()
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        components.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

        let ranges = [0,2,4].map {
            return str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: $0)..<str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: $0 + 2)
        }

        if let day = Int(str[ranges[0]]) {
            components.day = day
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        if let hour = Int(str[ranges[1]]), hour < 24 {
            components.hour = hour
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        if let minute = Int(str[ranges[2]]), minute < 60 {
            components.minute = minute
        } else {
            return nil
        }

        return components
    }
}

// This formatter is to convert the date to your local time. Configure to taste
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .medium

if var components = DateComponents.from(str: "071953Z") {
    components.year = 2017
    components.month = 4

    if let date = components.date {
        print(formatter.string(from: date))
    } else {
        print("\(components) does not make a valid date")
    }
}
```